# Share on Google Plus the link the sharing button stays beside

Tags: javascript

I have this:

[link to be shared][G+ button]

While I could find a way to share on Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn etc the link the sharing buttons stay besides, I couldn't find a way to share on G+.

Does anyone knows what is the URL to use for concatenation so it will share on G+?

I know that G+ offer a button to be used but I just don't want to use the whole JS included...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google recently released the "Google+ Share Link". It is now available here: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink

Example usage:

> https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks Chirag. Seems like the right solution. I will take a look when home. Thanks again.